# Generating all combinations of 1 and -1 in n Dimensions with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, combinations

I need a way to generate a numpy array with all possible combination of [-1, 1] given a number of dimensions.

For example If i have 2 dimensions I would get :
[[1, 1], [1, -1], [-1, 1], [-1, -1]]

If I have 3 dimensions I would get:
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, -1], [1, -1, 1], [1, -1, -1], [-1, 1, 1], [-1, 1, -1], [-1, -1, 1], [-1, -1, -1]],

I have tried something like this :

```
import numpy as np                      
def permgrid(n):
    inds = np.indices((2,) * n)
    return inds.reshape(n, -1).T
```

But this only returns all combinations of 0 and 1.

Comment: simply replace all your zeros with -1 then. Is the order of any importance?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the product function from itertools.

Basically, you get all the combinations with repeat of 2.

```
print (list(itertools.product([1,-1], repeat=2)))
```

> itertools.product(*iterables[, repeat])
>
> Cartesian product of input iterables.
>
> Roughly equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression.

You can read more in [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [`NumPy's broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) based method -

```
def broadcasting_typecast(n):
    return -2*((np.arange(2**n)[:,None] & (1 << np.arange(n-1,-1,-1))) != 0)+1
```

Sample runs -

```
In [231]: n = 2

In [232]: broadcasting_typecast(n)
Out[232]: 
array([[ 1,  1],
       [ 1, -1],
       [-1,  1],
       [-1, -1]])

In [233]: n = 3

In [234]: broadcasting_typecast(n)
Out[234]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1, -1],
       [ 1, -1,  1],
       [ 1, -1, -1],
       [-1,  1,  1],
       [-1,  1, -1],
       [-1, -1,  1],
       [-1, -1, -1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Either replace,

```
def permgrid(n):
    inds = np.indices((2,) * n)
    out = inds.reshape(n, -1).T
    return np.where(out==0, -np.ones_like(out), out)
```

or do it with math:

```
def permgrid(n):
    inds = np.indices((2,) * n)
    return inds.reshape(n, -1).T*2-1
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `-ones_like(out)` here. `-1` will do.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at `itertools`. It's a package for the generation of sorted sequences and the like.

```
import itertools as it

for element in it.combinations_with_replacement([1,-1],3):
  print element
```

Comment: I don't think this works; combinations are unordered.

Comment: No, they aren't. As mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: They may have an order by virtue of being lists, but not all orders of a combination are returned, which I think OP wants. From the docs: `combinations_with_replacement('ABCD', 2)` --> `AA AB AC AD BB BC BD CC CD DD`. `it.combinations_with_replacement([1,-1],3)` would only return `[1,1,1],[1,1,-1],[1,-1,-1],[-1,-1,-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `np.ix_`. advantage: you can easily replace `-1,1` with whatever you like (other numbers, other dtypes, more than 2, etc.)

```
>>> n = 3
>>> out = np.empty(n*(2,)+(n,), dtype=int)
>>> for j, sl in enumerate(np.ix_(*(n*((-1,1),)))):
...     out[..., j] = sl
... 
>>> out
array([[[[-1, -1, -1],
         [-1, -1,  1]],

        [[-1,  1, -1],
         [-1,  1,  1]]],


        [[[ 1, -1, -1],
         [ 1, -1,  1]],

        [[ 1,  1, -1],
         [ 1,  1,  1]]]])
```

Optionally:

```
flat_out = np.reshape(out, (-1, n))
```